# how to drop another view on Marker in android?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, google-maps-markers

I want to drop a other view on Marker and want to get detail of marker.

I have set All Details in Tag of Marker.
[How to enable Drag a Marker (Android Map Api v2) after a single Touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934224/how-to-enable-drag-a-marker-android-map-api-v2-after-a-single-touch)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#AboutDragListeners

i have a image view and i want to drop that image on Marker and want to get Tag of marker

Comment: detail of marker you mean to say the marker address latitude or longitude etc right ?

Comment: No, i have a image view and i want to drop that image on Marker and want to get Tag of marker

Comment: You mean you want to use image instead of marker ?

Comment: yes, but want to drop that image ON marker

Comment: I think you are asking about something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327960/how-do-i-implement-falling-pins-animation-for-markers-in-android-map-view

Comment: @Lokesh try to understand my problem, i don't want to drag drop marker. i have a image and want to drop that to marker and want to get detail of marker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141426/discussion-between-rohit-and-lokesh).